# Is it appropriate to create a new tag for a Ruby standard library?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There are 185,778 questions tagged [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby).

It reads:

> The [ruby] tag is for questions related to the Ruby language, including its syntax **and its libraries**.

But it seems that some of those libraries already have their tag:

- [erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erb) for https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html
- [fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fiddle) for https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fiddle/rdoc/Fiddle.html
- [irb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/irb) for https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html
- [mkmf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mkmf) for https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/mkmf/rdoc/MakeMakefile.html
- [rdoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdoc) for https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rdoc/rdoc/RDoc.html
- [rexml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rexml) for https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/
- [rubygems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rubygems) for https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem.html
- [thwait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/thwait) for https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/thwait/rdoc/ThWait.html
- [webrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webrick) for https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick.html

**Can we create new tags for some of the other Ruby libraries?**

Example for [Resolv](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv.html): could it be a tag [resolv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolv), [ruby-resolv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-resolv), or better stay no tag at all?
Example for [Psych](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html): could it be a tag [ruby-psych](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-psych)? (note: [psych](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/psych) is taken for something else)

Answer (score -2):

Every user with reputation over 1500 [can add new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags). Once it's added it appears in moderation tools, so users with rep >10k can react if it's inappropriate.

> However, note that:
>
> on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from
>   the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6
>   month period. meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag
>   on a question, are not allowed. Please create new tags responsibly!

Also,

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.
>   Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be
>   able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined
>   categories.

[--Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

So you should use tags freely, once you feel that certain key-word well defines a category.